# Tengo un pequeño teclado, como puedo hacer para que cada vez que pulse una tecla (botón), salga en un textview lo que vas escribiendo

Tags: java, android-studio

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero solo consigo que salga una letra

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView salidatexto;
            salidatexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSalida);
            Button objBoton = (Button) v;
            String letra = objBoton.getText().toString();
```

}

He probado mediante un keyevent pero no lo consigo, y estoy tratando de almacenar en un string vacío y que lo vaya mostrando, pero no se como hacerlo.
Los botones están creados de forma dinámica.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para que entiendas cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una pregunta correctamente. Las imágenes de código no son aceptables puesto que hacen que sea mucho más difícil de leer y puede dificultar el leer la pregunta en algunos dispositivos.

Comment: @Benito-B perdona perdona, iba con prisa y no me he dado cuenta de como lo había subido, gracias por la información ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView salidatexto;
    salidatexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSalida);
    Button objBoton = (Button) v;
    String letra = objBoton.getText().toString();
    salida = salidatexto.getText() + letra;
    salidatexto.setText(salida);
}
```

Nada nada, era tan sencillo como asignar a una cadena vacía y que fuese registrando y añadiendo cada letra después.

Comment: Si el código es texto, por qué lo pones como imagen?? por favor, edita pregunta y respuesta y déjalo como texto.